# UTF-8 in PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I need help with regular expressions. My string contains unicode characters and code below doesn't work.

First four characters must be numbers, then comma and then any alphabetic characters or whitespaces... 
I already read that if i add /u on end of regular expresion but it didn't work for me...

My code works with non-unicode characters

```
$post = '9999,škofja loka';;
echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{4},[\s]*[a-zA-Z]+', $post);
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 36):

**Updated answer:**
This is now tested and working

```
$post = '9999, škofja loka';
echo preg_match('/^\\d{4},[\\s\\p{L}]+$/u', $post);
```

`\\w` will not work, because it does not contain all unicode letters and contains also `[0-9_]` additionally to the letters.

Important is also the `u` modifier to activate the unicode mode.

If there can be letters **or** whitespace after the comma then you should put those into the same character class, in your regex there are 0 or more whitespace after the comma and then there are only letters.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html for php regex details

The `\\p{L}` (Unicode letter) is explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Important is also the use of the end of string boundary `$` to ensure that really the complete string is verified, otherwise it will match only the first whitespace and ignore the rest for example.

Comment: doesn't work = return 0:   $post = '9999,škofja loka';

echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{4},[\s\w]+/u', $post);

Comment: @gašper, so now I tested it [online](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and it seems that PHP needs to be double escaped `preg_match('/^\\d{4},[\\s\\w]+$/u', $post);` but it seems that `\\w`  does not include the unicode characters, even with `u` modifier.

Comment: @gašper, I did some more testing and updated my answer

Comment: can i use that regular expression also in js?

Comment: @gašper, I don't think so, [http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) is explaining the javascript regex flavour and it says that it does not support unicode (except you give the character explicitly, like `^\d{4},[\sa-zA-Zš]+$`)

Comment: there is a library for unicode in js and much more http://xregexp.com/

Answer (score 8):

`[a-zA-Z]` will match only letters in the range of a-z and A-Z. You have non-US-ASCII letters, and therefore your regex won't match, regardless of the `/u` modifier. You need to use the word character escape sequence (`\w`).

```
$post = '9999,škofja loka';
echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{4},[\s]*[\w]+/u', $post);
```

Comment: doesn' work in my case with your code

Comment: Note: `\w` will match numbers too, and `\s` doesn't need the square brackets.  Being concise: `/^\d{4},\s*\w+/u`

Comment: did you test it, still doesn't work

Comment: Even in UTF-8 mode, `\w` only matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  You have to use Unicode-specific constructs like `\p{L}` *as well as* the `/u` flag.

Comment: @Alan: Locale affects what is a letter and what is not. For me, the regex I posted works (fi_FI.UTF-8 locale).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is your regular expression. You are explicitly saying that you will only accept `a b c ... z A B C ... Z`. `š` is not in the a-z set. Remember, `š` is as different to `s` as any other character.

So if you really just want a sequence of letters, then you need to test for the unicode properties. e.g.

```
echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{4},[\s]*\p{L}+', $post);
```

That shouuld work because `\p{L}` matches any unicode character which is considered a letter. Not just A through Z.

Comment: This doesn't work right: this should return 0 but it return 1 $post = '9999,ščćžđkofja loka,.(?*';
echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{4},[\s]*\p{L}+/', $post);

Comment: One thing - in your test program is the $post program in UTF-8? Sorry I'm not that good at php. But in perl if you just enter the character `š` you get a string of one byte 9A. In UTF-8 that character needs to be two bytes C5 A1 (which looks like `Å¡` in a latin character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `u`, and remember the trailing slash:

```
echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{4},[\s]*[a-zA-Z]+/u', $post);
```

**Edited:**

```
echo preg_match('/^\d{4},(?:\s|\w)+/u', $post);
```

Comment: The `u` modifier alone is not enough, cf. @jmz's answer.

Comment: @jensgram: `\w` with the `u` modifier is not enough either; cf. @stema's answer. ;)

Comment: @alan Bah... I think I'll skip Monday morning in future...