# preg_replace non word characters is replacing UTF-8 chars

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace

I've got a strange issue where a preg_replace has different results on different servers.
When the following code is executed on my local wampserver:

```
echo preg_replace('/[\W]+/u', '-', "blāh bl*h");
```

The following is output:

```
"blāh-bl-h"
```

When executed on my remote server, the following is output:

```
"bl-h-bl-h"
```

The "ā" is also replaced.

The php installation on the local wampserver is 5.3.13, on the server it is 5.3.3-7+squeeze15. Is this a PHP version thing?

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407983/utf-8-in-php-regular-expressions

Comment: @sofl He is already using `\W` and not `[A-Z]`.  Mike, [looking here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php) not sure it is a different version of PCRE or not.  Maybe you check `phpinfo()` and make that determination.  Then check if your issue shows up in [change log](http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt).  I see diff. behavior from 5.2 to 5.3 for example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fk69OY

Comment: Yes thats right but I thought he could try something like `/[^\p{L}]+/u`

Comment: Ok, yes they are using different versions of PCRE - 8.02 vs 8.12. I'm not sure which point on the change log addresses the issue. I guess then i will work around it. I found that both `/[^\p{L}]+/u` and `mb_ereg_replace('/[\W]+/u', '-', "blāh bl*h")` work. My only question is why then does it take so long for debian to update their php stuff.. What are they waiting for?

Comment: Also make sure that your input string really is UTF-8 encoded text. There's countless ways how utf8 text gets garbled up by various processes (load/save files in a text editor, uploading via FTP, etc.)