# php preg_match get word with cyrillic characters

Tags: php, regex

I try to get some word from string, but this word maybe will have cyrillic characters, I try to get it, but all what I to do - not working.

Please help me;
My code

```
  $str= "Продавец:В KrossАдын рассказать друзьям  var addthis_config = {'data_track_clickback':true};";
$pattern = '/\s(\w*|.*?)\s/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

I need to get **KrossАдын**.

Thaks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 in PHP regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407983/utf-8-in-php-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your string uses UTF-8 characters, which \w will not match. Check this answer on StackOverflow for a solution: [UTF-8 in PHP regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407983/utf-8-in-php-regular-expressions)

Essentially, you'll want to add the `u` modifier at the end of your expression, and use `\p{L}` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the meaning of `\w` by using the u modifier. With the u modifier, the string is read as an UTF8 string, and the `\w` character class is no more `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`:

```
$pattern = '/\s(\w*|.*?)\s/u';
```

Note that the alternation in the pattern is a non-sense:

you use an alternation where the second member can match the same thing than the first. *(i.e. all that is matched by `\w*` can be matched by `.*?` because there is a whitespace on the right. The two subpatterns will match the characters between two whitespaces)*

Writting `$pattern = '/\s(.*?)\s/u';` does exactly the same, or better:

```
$pattern = '/\s(\S*)\s/u';
```

that avoids to use a lazy quantifier.

If your goal is only to match ASCII and cyrillic letters, the most efficient (because for character classes the smaller is the faster) will be:

```
$pattern = '~(*UTF8)[a-z\p{Cyrillic}]+~i';
```

`(*UTF8)` will inform the regex engine that the original string must be read as an UTF8 string.

`\p{Cyrillic}` is a character class that only contains cyrillic letters.